# UIRefreshControl stops me from being able to tap on tableView Cells in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, pull-to-refresh, uirefreshcontrol

I have a tableViewController that displays an array of users pulled from parse. I added 'pull to refresh' via `UIRefreshControl` but every time it hits `refresher.endRefresher()` it makes it so I can't tap the top cell in the list and the second cell is only tappable at the very bottom of the cell, right near the top of the third cell. I can't figure out why the refresher is doing this. 
Here's a [short video showing what is happening](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hwvskoatrfputwm/Instagram%20Bug.mov?dl=0):

Below is my refresh function and my `viewDidLoad` func.

```
var refresher: UIRefreshControl!

func refresh() {

    let query = PFUser.query()
    query?.orderByAscending("username")

    query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

        if let users = objects {

            self.usernames.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
            self.userids.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
            self.isFollowing.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

            for object in users {

                if let user = object as? PFUser {

                    if user.objectId! != PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId {

                        self.usernames.append(user.username!)
                        self.userids.append(user.objectId!)

                        let query = PFQuery(className: "followers")

                        query.whereKey("follower", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)
                        query.whereKey("following", equalTo: user.objectId!)

                        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in
                            if let objects = objects {
                                if objects.count > 0 {
                                    self.isFollowing[user.objectId!] = true
                                } else {
                                    self.isFollowing[user.objectId!] = false
                                }
                            }

                            if self.isFollowing.count == self.usernames.count {
                                self.tableView.reloadData()
                                print("refreshed")
                                self.refresher.endRefreshing()
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    refresher = UIRefreshControl()
    refresher.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
    refresher.addTarget(self, action: "refresh", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

    self.tableView.addSubview(refresher)
    refresh()
}
```

## UPDATE

I figured out what was happening and how to solve it. It seems as if the 'pull to refresh' feature was blocking most of my top two cells once I pulled the first time, so the solution was to send the refresher to the back in `viewDidLoad` via `tableView.sendSubviewToBack(refresher)`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    refresher = UIRefreshControl()
    refresher.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
    refresher.addTarget(self, action: "refresh", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    self.tableView.addSubview(refresher)
    tableView.sendSubviewToBack(refresher)
    refresh()
}
```